# Neo4J/Cypher: How to filter the nodes of a path?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I want to get all the `simple cycles`/`circuits` on a graph that go through a given node. I am able to  so with this cypher query:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*]->(n)
WHERE n.postId = 71 //postId is a node property
RETURN nodes(p)
```

However, the above retrieves duplicate nodes within the 'circuit' (except from the start and the end nodes), which is not a circuit at all according to the graph theory.

With the following query I can remove those duplicates in the circuit but I have to limit the length of the circuit or path in the `MATCH` pattern which is kind of hardcoding it.

```
// In this example the length of the path is hardcoded to 4
MATCH p=
    (n)-[:RELATES_TO]->
    (p2)-[:RELATES_TO]->
    (p3)-[:RELATES_TO]->
    (p4)-[:RELATES_TO]->(n)
WHERE n.postId = 71
    AND p2.postId <> 71
    AND p3.postId <> 71
    AND p4.postId <> 71
RETURN nodes(p)
```

Is there a way to filter the nodes between the relationships in the first query?

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*]->(n)
WHERE n.postId = 71 //postId is a node property
RETURN nodes(p)
```

Important notes:

- I know how to limit the length of the path (via the WHERE length() constraint or with [variable length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_variable_length))

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [`filter()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-filter) or [`none()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-none)? I think I correctly understood your problem but here's how I am using the above functions. (If this is off, just downwote.)

The gist: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=99xkcu

```
CREATE
  (g:Person {name: 'Gorduin'}), (a:Person {name: 'Alvaro'}),
  (pn:PhoneNumber {number: '555-512-2017'}),
  (e11:Extension {extension: 11}),
  (e27:Extension {extension: 27}),
  (e19:Extension {extension: 19}),

  (e11)-[:extension_of]->(pn)<-[:extension_of]-(e27),
  (e19)-[:extension_of]->(pn),

  (g)<-[:phone_number_of]-(e11),
  (g)<-[:phone_number_of]-(e27),
  (a)<-[:phone_number_of]-(e19),
  (a)<-[:phone_number_of]-(pn);
```

[image]

Variable length query needs to be used because the `:phone_number_of` pointer can originate from the extension (linking to the phone number) or the phone number itself. Arrow directions don't matter, you can reverse any of them and try the queries below.

> (Limiting the length of the query would be the obvious solution in my
>   case such as
>
> ```
> MATCH path = (p:Person)-[*1..3]-(n:PhoneNumber)
> RETURN nodes(path);
> ```
>
> but that wasn't the OP's question.)

---

(1) Getting every possible path from a person to a phone number (edited for readability):

```
MATCH path = (p:Person)-[*]-(n:PhoneNumber)
RETURN nodes(path) as every_possible_path_from_a_Person_to_a_PhoneNumber;

╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"every_possible_path_from_a_Person_to_a_PhoneNumber"                  │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[a,pn]                                                                │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[g,e11,pn,e19,a,pn]                                                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[g,e27,pn,e19,a,pn]                                                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[g,e11,pn]                                                            │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[a,pn,e27,g,e11,pn]                                                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[a,e19,pn,e27,g,e11,pn]                                               │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[a,e19,pn]                                                            │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[g,e11,pn,a,e19,pn]                                                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[g,e27,pn,a,e19,pn]                                                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[g,e27,pn]                                                            │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[a,pn,e11,g,e27,pn]                                                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[a,e19,pn,e11,g,e27,pn]                                               │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

(2) Using `none()` to remove redundancy by filtering out paths that contain a specific node (a node with certain properties or labels):

```
MATCH path = (p:Person)-[*]-(n:PhoneNumber)
WITH nodes(path) as ns
WHERE NONE(node IN ns WHERE (exists(node.name) and node.name ='Gorduin'))
RETURN ns as path_nodes_NOT_containing_a_specific_person;

╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"path_nodes_NOT_containing_a_specific_person"                 │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[a,pn]                                                        │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[a,e19,pn]                                                    │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

(3) Using `filter()` to remove a specific node from the returned paths:

```
MATCH path = (p:Person)-[*]-(n:PhoneNumber)
WITH nodes(path) as ns
WHERE NONE(node IN ns WHERE (exists(node.name) and node.name ='Gorduin'))
RETURN filter(node in ns  WHERE NOT node:Person) as personless_nodelist;

╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"personless_nodelist"                                         │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[pn]                                                          │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[e19,pn]                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out the APOC Procedures Library, specifically the [allSimplePaths](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress) function in the Graph Algorithms section. Simple paths should have no repeating nodes.

EDIT

Note that currently the algorithm can't currently be used as-is to find simple cycles where the start and end node are the same.

However, if you define the end nodes as the second-to-last step in the cycle, all adjacent nodes to the start node that have a directed relationship to the start node, then you should be able to get your result (though the path obviously won't include the final traversal to the start node to complete the cycle).

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon, I will take a look. Didn't know such amazing plugin exists...! :)

Comment: I execute the `allSimplePaths` procedure this way `MATCH (from:Post{postId:71}), (to:Post{postId:71})
CALL apoc.algo.allSimplePaths(from, to, 'RELATES_TO', 5) yield path
RETURN *`
It returns a single node, the one with the property `postId = 71`

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll log a bug on that tomorrow.

Comment: I created the [feature request](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/134) for this. I also updated my answer to include a workaround that still uses allSimplePaths.

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be as fast as using using the allSimplePaths APOC procedure, as suggested by @InverseFalcon (I have not tried it), here is a away to get simple paths in pure Cypher:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*]->(n)
WHERE n.postId = 71
WITH NODES(p) AS nds
UNWIND nds AS nd
WITH nds, COUNT(DISTINCT nd) AS dnd
WHERE dnd = LENGTH(nds)-1
RETURN nds;
```

Basically, this query requires that the number of *distinct* nodes in a path is equal to the number nodes minus one (since the last node must be the same as the first).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, this seems to calculate all the simple paths allowing duplicates, then remove the paths that have duplicate nodes. Is that correct?

Comment: In Cypher, you can't influence the traversal of the variable-length relationship (that would be imperative, where Cypher is declarative), so any solution is bound to filter after the fact. Using the Java [traversal API](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorial-traversal), you could stop the traversal beyond a given path as soon as a duplicate is found, including the result if it's the same as the start node, excluding it otherwise.